# shell script to add "noexec" and "nosuid" to /var partition

Tags: regex, sed, grep, fstab

I'm trying to create a small script to add noexec and nosuid to `/var` partition by modifying the `/etc/fstab` file.

Currently, the `/etc/fstab` also contains /var/log partition apart from `/var` partition.

When I run my script the changes are being made to both `/var` and `/var/log`. i only want to add "noexec" and "nosuid" to the `/var` partition.

Here is what I wrote

```
#cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
egrep -q  '/var/.+noexec' /etc/fstab || sed -ri '/\/var/ s/defaults/defaults,noexec/' /etc/fstab
egrep -q  '/var/.+noexec' /etc/fstab || sed -ri '/\/var/ s/defaults,nodev/defaults,nodev,noexec/' /etc/fstab
egrep -q  '/var/.+nosuid' /etc/fstab || sed -ri '/\/var/ s/defaults/defaults,nosuid/' /etc/fstab
```

1. current /etc/fstab entry  w.r.t /var and /var/log is given below,

```
cat /etc/fstab

/dev/mapper/system-var  /var                    ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2

/dev/mapper/system-varlog /var/log                ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2
```

2. after running script, the output is as below,

```
/dev/mapper/system-var  /var                    ext4    defaults,nosuid,noexec,nodev        1 2

/dev/mapper/system-varlog /var/log                ext4    defaults,nosuid,noexec,nodev        1 2
```

3. The expected output is given below,

```
cat /etc/fstab

/dev/mapper/system-var  /var                    ext4    defaults,nosuid,noexec,nodev        1 2

/dev/mapper/system-varlog /var/log                ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to add a traling whitespace character to your grep pattern just after `/var` like so:

```
egrep '/var\s' /etc/fstab
```

`\s` stands for **whitespace** in many REGEX implementations (sed, perl...), which consists of space, tab and some other characters.